# How to open a bootstrap modal using a function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
  sample(){


      //call modal
       if($('#myModal').length) {
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
       } else {
      alert("mymodal could not be found.");
     } 
     }

    }

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Attention user.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Above is my modal. I want to call this modal inside the function sample(),if the if condition evaluates to true. I used Jquery to call it.But it is not working,else part is getting executed.Pls help me fix it.**

Comment: what is showModal1?

Comment: Why are you using `jquery` with Angular. Please undo this before you move furthur on this code. Use component supported libraries like materail.io. Also You need to provide more code and what's not working , and what error are you getting.

Comment: I'm not getting any error,  but the modal is not showing up. Is there any other way to call a modal inside a function?

Comment: I've edited my code @Cagri. That was a mistake